# I'm starting an activity from a broadcast receiver, but why is my other activity also starting?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

In my app, there is an `MainActivity` and an `AlarmActivity`. `MainActivity` is used to set an alarm. `AlarmActivity` is used to show the alarm. In the middle, I have a class that implements `BroadcastReceiver`, to receive the pending intent that was scheduled in `MainActivity`. The issue I'm having is two fold.

1) `MainActivity` is being created when I'm only expecting `AlarmActivity` to be created from the onReceive method seen below.

2)When `AlarmActivity` does get created, it is destroyed right afterwards. Please see my logs below.

Please note, this ONLY happens when I turn the screen off. If I destroy `MainActivity` and keep the screen on until the alarm goes off, all is well. If I let `MainActivity`  live, and keep the screen on, `AlarmActivity` shows up on top of `MainActivity` , as expected. Otherwise, if the screen is OFF... AlarmActivity is shown for a split second, then it disappears, and I see MainActivity  on screen. What gives?

Here is where I schedule the alarm. Not that the callingContext variable is the context from my MainActivity class.

```
 Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this.callingContext, AlarmActivity.class);

        //Get the Alarm Service
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) callingContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

     //user our intent and give it a time to broadcast at
          alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarmTime, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.callingContext, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
```

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

    final String TAG=this.toString();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onReceive");

        //start a new activity, an alarm has gone off

        //See that I've tried using the application context, but this did not help.
        //Context context=arg0.getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent=new Intent(arg0,AlarmActivity.class);

        //This flag is required for starting an activity outside of an activity.
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_STARTED_FROM_BROADCAST_RECEIVER",true);
        arg0.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Alarm Activity lifecycle methods.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");
        if(savedInstanceState==null) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_alarm);


        }
    }

    public static void acquireScreenCpuWakeLock(Context context) {
        if (sCpuWakeLock != null) {
            return;
        }
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        sCpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "TYLER");
        sCpuWakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public static void releaseCpuLock() {
        if (sCpuWakeLock != null) {
            sCpuWakeLock.release();
            sCpuWakeLock = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.i(TAG,"onResume");
        super.onResume();

    //  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.alarm_frame, new AlarmFragment()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.i(TAG,"onStart");
        super.onStart();
        final Window win = getWindow();
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
        acquireScreenCpuWakeLock(this);
        alarmFragment=new AlarmFragment();
        alarmFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.alarm_frame, alarmFragment).commit();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        Log.i(TAG,"onPause");
        super.onPause();
        releaseCpuLock();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(alarmFragment);
        Log.d("pfaff","wakelock released, alarm activity paused");

    }

   @Override
    protected  void onDestroy(){
       Log.i(TAG,"onDestroy");
       super.onDestroy();
     //  wakeLock.release();
        Log.d("pfaff","alarm activity destroyed");
   }

}
```

Alarm Framgnet lifecycle methods.

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        Log.i(TAG,"onAttach");
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity=activity;//camera

    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
       Log.i(TAG,"onResume");
        super.onResume();
        final AlarmFragment thisFragment = this;
}

@Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(this.toString(),"onPause");
        super.onPause();
        getActivity().onBackPressed();

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(this.toString(),"onDestroy");

        super.onDestroy();
       // tearDownMedia();
        scanMyMedia();
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        if(timeReceiverIsRegistered) {
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }
```

here is the logcat:

```
   11-27 21:56:46.036  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/com.example.videoalarmt.AlarmReceiver@41eb2158﹕ onReceive
    11-27 21:56:46.066  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/com.example.videoalarmt.MainActivity@41eaaf08﹕ onCreate
    11-27 21:56:46.066  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/timePickerFragment{41ea1e58}﹕ onCreateView
    11-27 21:56:46.096  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt E/TextView﹕ Saved cursor position 2/2 out of range for (restored) text
    11-27 21:56:46.096  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt E/TextView﹕ Saved cursor position 2/2 out of range for (restored) text
    11-27 21:56:46.136  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/com.example.videoalarmt.AlarmActivity@41ed7bf8﹕ onCreate
    11-27 21:56:46.136  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/com.example.videoalarmt.AlarmActivity@41ed7bf8﹕ onStart
    11-27 21:56:46.136  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/com.example.videoalarmt.AlarmActivity@41ed7bf8﹕ onResume
    11-27 21:56:46.136  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/AlarmFragment{41edaa40}﹕ onAttach
    11-27 21:56:46.136  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/AlarmFragment{41edaa40}﹕ onViewCreated
    11-27 21:56:46.136  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/AlarmFragment{41edaa40}﹕ onStart
    11-27 21:56:46.136  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/AlarmFragment{41edaa40}﹕ onResume
    11-27 21:56:46.136  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/AlarmFragment{41edaa40}﹕ was started from broadcast receiver
    11-27 21:56:46.206  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/AlarmFragment{41edaa40 #0 id=0x7f0a0024}﹕ onPause
    11-27 21:56:46.206  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/com.example.videoalarmt.AlarmActivity@41ed7bf8﹕ onPause
    11-27 21:56:46.787  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/AlarmFragment{41edaa40 #0 id=0x7f0a0024}﹕ Putting media recorder in PREPARED state from DATASOURCECONFIGURED state
    11-27 21:56:46.787  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/MediaRecorderJNI﹕ prepare: surface=0x76608e58
    11-27 21:56:47.137  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
    11-27 21:56:47.137  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    11-27 21:56:47.237  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/com.example.videoalarmt.AlarmActivity@41ed7bf8﹕ onStop
    11-27 21:56:47.598  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/AlarmFragment{41edaa40 #0 id=0x7f0a0024}﹕ onDestroy
    11-27 21:56:47.598  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/com.example.videoalarmt.AlarmActivity@41ed7bf8﹕ onDestroy
    11-27 21:56:47.658  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    11-27 21:57:02.243  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/com.example.videoalarmt.MainActivity@41eaaf08﹕ onDestroy
```

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.videoalarmt"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
        >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

           <receiver android:name="com.example.videoalarmt.AlarmReceiver"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.videoalarmt.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name="com.example.videoalarmt.AlarmActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        </activity>

            <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: use `intent` instead of `arg0` in startactivity();

Comment: `arg0.startActivity()` in that arg0 is a Context not Intent.

Comment: startActivity is a method to be called on Context object, not an intent object. Right? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

Comment: `Intent intent=new Intent(sourceActivity.this,DestinationActivity.class);`
`startActivity(intent);`

Comment: This is how it works.

Comment: That is not how it works my friend, startActivity() is called from a Context and an intent is passed in.

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya I see you've edited your comment. So NOW that is how it works. intent.startActivity(intent) is incorrect. In your edited comment, you are using an implicit this in front of startActivity which is a CONTEXT :)

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that :D

Comment: post your manifest please.

Comment: I'm confused with alarm manager you don't need a receiver.  Is the alarm starting main and the broadcast receiver starting the alarmactivity? or something along those lines.

Comment: Can you post the code that schedules the alarm? Also danny117 is right, why do you start a broadcast receiver that starts your AlarmActivity instead of using a PendingIntent to start the activity directly?

Comment: I didnt' go down the route of the pending intent because the docs say it's primary use is for.. "  a PendingIntent is to grant permission to a foreign application to use the contained Intent as if it were executed from your app's own process." Should I be using a PendingIntent to call an activity within my own application? Will a PendingIntent stick around after my application has been killed? I've posted the code where I schedule the alarm.

Comment: When I bypass the broadcast receiver and use a PendingIntent directly with AlarmManager, my MainActivity is no longer started. However, AlarmActivity is still being destroyed immediately.

Comment: PendingIntents must be used in this case because the AlarmManager is a system process and this qualifies as "foreign application". The PendingIntent will stick around as long as it hasn't been delivered. Since there's no code for your AlarmActivity / AlarmFragment there's no way to tell why it terminates.

Comment: If you're still interested in solving this, post your AlarmActivity / AlarmFragment code

Comment: @TylerPfaff see my answer below. You shouldn't be calling `getActivity().onBackPressed()` in `onPause` in your Fragment

Comment: go with getActivity().finish()

Comment: Note that AlarmActivity->onCreate should always call it's super.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why MainActivity is being created. Only problem I found with your code is in below line:

```
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this.callingContext, AlarmActivity.class);
```

Here you are creating a intent with Activity class but in your pending intent you are using getBroadCast() method. It should be:

```
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this.callingContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
```

I have not tried your code but this can be a cause of your issue.
Please make this change and check if Mainactivity is still getting created?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code and logs I think your problem is calling `onBackPressed` in your fragment.

```
11-27 21:56:46.206  29370-29370/com.example.videoalarmt I/AlarmFragment{41edaa40 #0 id=0x7f0a0024}﹕ onPause
```

Your AlarmFragment.onPause should not be calling `getActivity().onBackPressed()`. This is most likely what is causing your activity to close. Simply remove that line in AlarmFragment.onPause and I think your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver, you can not perform operation more then 10sec.  [see here official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)  .

when screen is lock then cpu stop working [see here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/index.html)

so when screen lock then and cpu stop working and time gets more then 10 sec that time you get this error.

so prevent from this error you should you [wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html). using this your application when screen lock.
and also see this [link1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) [link2](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

I hope my informations is helpful for you to resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
intent intent = new Intent(context, WordService.class);  
context.startService(intent);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to others to also include a brief explanation of why/how the code solves the problem.

Comment: WordService.class is just a example u can put here ur own class which u wonna call by broadcaste reciver

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from you this behaviour appear. When you open your main activity and then set the alarm then close the screen before the alarm receiver gets it. then when you turn the screen on again you see the alarm activity flashes and disappear.

Based on this here is the explanation:

> Since it work in background, the receiver gets the alarm while the
>   screen is off. what is happening that the receiver start the alarm
>   activity and since the screen is off the alarm activity get paused and
>   the alarm fragment closes it. but, all these events get stacked until
>   you unlock the screen and you see all of them happening.

You can postpone the alarm activity launch after the screen gets on. When alarm receiver get something, check for screen. if it closed save the alarm settings in the SharedPreferances. You can set a broadcast receiver to check the screen events on and off. on screen on check your shared preferences for a postponed alarm and start your alarm activity after you clear your shared preferences.

Another solution is to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

permission to your manifest and set the screen on when your receiver gets something. and in your screen on receiver start your alarm activity.

You also should use go with `getActivity().finish()` not `getActivity().onBackPressed()` to close an activity.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever the lock button is pressed the app goes into pause mode.If you want your application to do something (or keep doing something) you need to handle this in the onPause() method of your main activity.

Comment: This is not applicable to my scenario